# Recover projects lost from the workspace after updating STS/ Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I performed an update of SpringSource Tool Suite (workspace name alludes to STS version 3.81) and after the update apparently finished, about 25-30 projects has disappeared from the workspace folder!!! I am using a Macbook Pro (MacOS Sierra). Right now, I just have a `.metadata` folder in the workspace:

```
.metadata/
└── version.ini
```

and contents of `version.ini` is:

```
#Wed Apr 18 19:44:34 PDT 2018
org.eclipse.core.runtime=2
org.eclipse.platform=4.6.3.v20170301-0400
```

1. I used the *nix find command `find / -name <names-of-some-files-from-some-of-those-projects>` *(essentially searching from the root of the hard drive)*
2. Spotlight Search
3. Finder Search

Nothing is showing up, so it looks like those folders are gone. How did this happen? I would think the update process would warn me, if it is going to empty the workspace.

Comment: an update process should definitely not empty the workspace or delete anything from disc with is project related. In case something went wrong and the workspace metadata got deleted or corrupted, the projects themselves should still be there on disc with all their related data and metadata - and you should be able to re-import them into the workspace again. Do you remember whether you had those projects located in the workspace itself or somewhere else (and just imported into the workspace)?

Comment: All the projects were in the workspace folder and not imported from anywhere else. I have often felt frustrated about Eclipse's inability to delineate the equivalent of "OS files" versus "user data files". My projects are my own data and all the Eclipse/STS related artifacts and files should be independent and not intertwined such that this happens. Perhaps I did not set up the workspace and/or projects correctly. Most of the projects are in Git, but I lost work done in my local copy in the past 2 weeks, which is actually quite substantial.

Comment: Loosing work from 2 weeks sounds absolutely horrible and I have no idea how this could happen while upgrading Eclipse/STS. The project data should not be touched by an update, independent of where the project is located. I usually have all my projects cloned from Git in a specific location and then only import them into Eclipse/STS without copying them into the workspace. That works pretty nicely. Unfortunately I don't have any idea where your projects ended up, they should definitely not be deleted from your drive while upgrading the IDE. Not sure how I can provide more help here. Any idea?

Comment: I imagine I am at fault too, and it is possible I naively overlooked some sign of impending disaster during the update process. It was a really painful week and taught me a good lesson, to protect myself and take additional precautions when performing an upgrade of anything, going forward. I appreciate the empathy!